# Will this combination work?

Tags: memory

I am using a dell PC( Dell Inspiron 620s, brought on 2012). It's having an Intel Pentium Dual core processor and memory of 2GB DDR3 stick( 240 pins), system runs on win 7 Ultimate 64 bit.
My question is will there be any problem if I install a RAM stick of 4 GB along with this 2GB( I cannot add two 2GB sticks with the current one because I have only two slots for memory)

Comment: Its unlikely your system supports 6GB so your only choice would be to use 2 2GB modules.

Comment: @Ramhound What about two 4GB modules?

Comment: @Ramhound: Mismatched sticks should still work. Tricky thing is how much the system can handle, and that should be in the manual.

Comment: @RogUE - I still question if the system supports more then 4GB even being installed due to the age of it. **Without the exact processor model I can't say one way or another.**  If your system does not support 6GB then it doesn't support 8GB

Comment: @Ramhound how can I find the "exact processor model"?

Comment: @RogUE, I don't want to get all space crazy here and think too outside the box, but, did you try the manual? :) Either way, what you want won't cause any issues so try it?

Comment: @Ramhound There's nothing mentioned in the manual.

Comment: @Ramhound However, I shall give a try to it.

Comment: System is 64 bit so it's ok, you only have to see does the motherboard supports your new memory and will two different sticks work together.